# Error en la consulta: check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysqli

```
$ext_query = "";
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $ext_query = " where bid=".$_GET['id'];
}

$query = $db->query('SELECT server_name, bid, player_id, player_ip, ban_created, player_nick, admin_nick, admin_id, admin_ip, ban_reason, ban_length, expired  FROM '.$dbTable .$ext_query ) or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
```

edite la anterior consulta y la estoy realizando de esta manera ahora

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT amx_bans.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash FROM amx_bans '.$ext_query.' LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id LEFT JOIN pug_serverstats ON pug_serverstats.pug_index = pug_playerstats.pug_index ORDER BY bid') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));
```

pero a la hora de consultar me salta este error

Error en la consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player...' at line 1

ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Que trae **$ext_query**?? Puedes poner un echo de la query como tal? Ya has probado esa query en un DBM??

Comment: **$ext_query** trae un status, es que modifique la query para poder obtener otro datos aparte pero al editar la query me empezo a dar ese problema

Comment: Ahi actualice el post añadi el apartado del **$ext_query**

Comment: Ahora has lo otro que te pedí. Imprime un echo de la query a ver si no tiene algún error y esa query deberías probarla en un DBM para ver que traiga lo que tu quieres. Como sabrás, al no poder replicar tu DB no se pueden hacer pruebas reales, solo podemos confiar en lo que vemos.

Comment: Es que no puedo imprimir ya que esta query sale unicamente cuando consulto los datos de una persona pero al salirme el error ese no me dara nada y soy nuevo que es un DBM?

Comment: agregue la consulta como me funcionaba antes de editarla que pasa, lo que hago es llamar un status y al darle click a un usuarioi este me muestra los datos de ese usuario unicamente ahora edite la consulta porque busco aparte de los datos que ya buscaba obtener otros pero a la hora de hacer la consulta me salta el error

Comment: Un DBM es un Data Base Manager, osea un Gestor de Bases de Datos. PHPmyAdmin, Navicat... Y has puesto la query con variables otra vez. Cuando te digo que imprimas la query es para ver que no tengas algún carácter o concatenador que genere un error en la sintaxis. (SELEC * FROM table WHERE id=12345) algo así es lo que seria bueno de ver.  Si te fijas el error dice que tienes un **Error de Sintaxis cerca del LEFT JOIN**. Ojo que estoy a punto de salir de la oficina, sino te respondo ya sabrás porque es.

Comment: el problema viene es cuando agrego el **$ext_query** y si te fijas esta al lado del **LEFT JOIN** lo que busco es añadir el **$ext_query** a esa query ya que gracias a esa variable es que consuto los datos de un **status**

Comment: Si quito la variable **$ext_query** me funciona bien me muestra los datos pero que pasa me salen los datos de toda la tabla y gracias a la variable hago que solo me muestre los datos del status al que yo quiero y no de todos si me entiendes

Comment: Depura la consulta: asigna la consulta a una variable, imprime la variable y manda como argumento de `$db->query()` dicha variable.

Comment: como podría hacer eso no tengo tanto conocimiento?

Comment: ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la formación de tu sentencia Select, la parte:

```
 amx_bans '.$ext_query.' LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id LEFT JOIN
```

Se traduce a algo como esto:

```
 amx_bans WHERE condiciones LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id LEFT JOIN
```

El WHERE no puede anteceder a los JOIN y es error de sintaxis. Agrega .ext_query la final de los Joins y antes del ORDER BY

Tu línea debe ser asi:

```
$query = $db->query('SELECT amx_bans.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash FROM amx_bans LEFT JOIN pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id LEFT JOIN pug_serverstats ON pug_serverstats.pug_index = pug_playerstats.pug_index '.$ext_query.' ORDER BY bid')
```

Comment: Lo interprete de esta manera `$query = $db->query('SELECT amx_bans.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash FROM amx_bans WHERE amx_bans '.$ext_query.' LEFT JOIN .ext_query pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = amx_bans.player_id LEFT JOIN .ext_query pug_serverstats ON pug_serverstats.pug_index = pug_playerstats.pug_index .ext_query ORDER BY bid') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: pero me salta error a la hora de consultar **Error en la consulta: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where bid=2 LEFT JOIN .ext_query pug_playerstats ON pug_playerstats.player_st...' at line 1**

Comment: Porque el where precede al left join

Comment: pero como lo podria hacer funcionar osea para que la consulta la haga sin errores?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciono <3 <3

Comment: Es lo que tiene saber que es lo que va a llegar al DBM. Siempre prueba tu query en el DBM antes de pasarla a código con variables.